# How to set user data after createUserWithEmailAndPassword (web)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have search on other questions but I can't find anything, so I'm sorry if this is a duplicated.

I'm trying to save extra user data on sign up to database, the signup is not a problem but I can't store the data, I'm trying this:

```
//add a real time listener
   firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(firebaseUser =>{



    if (user != null) {


      firebase.database().ref().child( firebaseUser.uid ).set( {
        /**store data**/
      } );

    console.log("Sign-in provider: "+ firebaseUser.providerId);
    console.log("Provider-specific UID: "+ firebaseUser.uid);
    console.log("name: "+firebaseUser.name);
    console.log("email: "+firebaseUser.email);
    console.log("country:"+firebaseUser.country);
     //console.log("  Photo URL: "+firebaseUser.photoURL);



    //window.location.href = "index.html";


     }else{
      console.log('not logged in');

     }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store any of the properties of the [Firebase User](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User). This should work:

```
firebase.database().ref().child( firebaseUser.uid ).set( {
    firebaseUser.displayName,
    lastSignInTimestamp: Date.now()
});
```

If that doesn't work, your user might not have permission to write to the location in the database. To troubleshoot that, attach an error listener:

```
firebase.database().ref().child( firebaseUser.uid ).set( {
    firebaseUser.displayName,
    lastSignInTimestamp: Date.now()
}.catch(function(error) {
    console.error(error);
});
```

If indeed it's a security problem, see the first blue note in the [Firebase documentation about writing data to the database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/save-data).